# LO Writer: Getting page number 1 for pages 1 and 2

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, page-numbers, field-codes

I'm writing this document (with the file originally having been an MS-Word .doc file) with LibreOffice Writer (4.3.3.2). I'm using a page number field in my header, but instead of the pages being numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 they're numbered 1, 1, 2, 3. There are no section breaks or page breaks in the document.

What could be the cause of this situation, and how can I fix it?